# Unable to alert the second alert message

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing an HTML code where in there is a button, once I click that button, there should be 2 alerts to be shown from JS and here is my code.

**HTML:**

```
<button id="chat" class="animated-chat tada" onclick="loadChatbox()" style="position: absolute; bottom: 90px; right: 490px;width: 80px; height: 30px; font-size:25px">Chat</button>
<div class="chatHeader">
  <span class="chat-text" style="text-align: center;">Chat with Care!!</span>
  <div id="close-chat" class="close">&times;</div>
  <div id="minim-chat" onclick="minimChatbox()">
    <span class="minim-button">&minus;</span>
  </div>
  <div id="maxi-chat" onclick="loadChatbox()">
    <span class="maxi-button">&plus;</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function loadChatbox() {
  alert("Hi");
  alertAgain();
}

function alertAgain() {
  var e = document.getElementById("minim-chat");
  e.style.display = "block";
  var e = document.getElementById("maxi-chat");
  e.style.display = "none";
  var e = document.getElementById("chatbox");
  e.style.margin = "0";
  alert("2nd alert");
}
```

Here when I click the `Chat` button, `alert("Hi");` is being alerted. but when I comment out the below part.

```
  var e = document.getElementById("minim-chat");
  e.style.display = "block";
  var e = document.getElementById("maxi-chat");
  e.style.display = "none";
  var e = document.getElementById("chatbox");
  e.style.margin = "0";
```

I can see even `alert("2d alert")`. This is really confusing. P lease let me know where I am going wrong and how can I fix this.

Here is the working fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/8kpxwroa/

Thanks

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt, sorry, my bad. Thanks for the poke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second alert is not working because your javascript code is breaking at:

```
var e = document.getElementById("chatbox");
```

In your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8kpxwroa/), if you check the console you will find this

[image]

This is because document cant find `chatbox` id in your code. So either remove this line

```
var e = document.getElementById("chatbox");
```

or just place a element in your html having `chatbox` id

Answer (score 1):

This is causing error

```
var e = document.getElementById("chatbox");
 e.style.margin = "0";
```

in your HTML you dont have any tag with "chatbox" id. so when it try to execute getting "Cannot read property 'style' of null" check console.

so try to add "chatbox" id or remove it.

Answer (score 0):

> I can see even alert("2d alert"). This is really confusing. P lease
>   let me know where I am going wrong and how can I fix this.

Based on source-code you have shared, **you don't have an element with *id* `chatbox`**

So , `document.getElementById("chatbox")` returns `null` and you are getting an error in your browser's console while executing next line

```
e.style.margin = "0";
```

Since `e` is null, JS engine will give an error and next statement (`alert`) will not be executed.

Looks like you want to hide the `chatheader` (updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8kpxwroa/8/))

```
var e = document.querySelector(".chatHeader");
e.style.margin = "0";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML code has no id with name **chatbox**. So replace it with id **chat**

```
var e = document.getElementById("chatbox");
```

become

```
var e = document.getElementById("chat");
```

See below URL : -

https://jsfiddle.net/8kpxwroa/14/